# CSS Hover: how to deal with multiple images for the "hover on everything but" CSS trick?

Tags: image, button, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-class

Here's the example code using a unique CSS trick:
http://dabblet.com/gist/39d1dec4f1be8c01bb25010dda986922

The only thing I want to change:
Change the three "A" image buttons to image button "A", image button "B" and image button "C".

How can I accomplish this using CSS without linking images inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply to link each image: A,B,C in a separate `<li>` in CSS. Then use a div that surrounds the whole `<ul>` in the HTML to replace the images in the "hover on everything but" buttons.

You can see the solution here:
http://dabblet.com/gist/08d37a65488d85c290887be76a33a2ad